# How to remove Race Face crankset?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, crankset

I have a Race Face Ride XC single ring crankset that I stripped out the pedal threads on one arm.  I am trying to remove the crankset, I have followed the instructions that came with the crankset, and it is not budging.  I have a Park Tool CWP-7 and have tried to use it (following any instructions I could find) and got nowhere.  I have soaked it in WD-40 for a week and have pounded on it with a hammer, and its still stuck.  There is supposed to be an "extractor bolt" but the only piece I have to "extract" is the end-cap bolt on the drive-side.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a different crank puller?

Comment: A picture would surely help. Take a look here: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-installation-and-removal-square-spindle-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Park Tool CWP-7` is the tool for this job. Remove the outer cap using an allen key and then install the CWP-7. There is no need to tighten it ultra hard. Then use an allen key on the CWP-7 and start tightening the bolt. The extractor will "penetrate" the crank and the crank arm will start detaching itself from the other crank arm which also has the spindle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I actually didn't realize that the little end caps come off the tool and they needed to swap ends.  Finally got it off, now to deal with the new crank and some wobble at the spindle...